# How can I dismiss the color picker that appears with an NSColorWell

Tags: xcode, macos, nscolorwell

A HUD popup window in my app includes an **NSColorWell** so that the user can chose a color for data on a graph.

Once the user clicks the NSColorWell, the Color Picker appears - thats good so far.
Once they have finished with the HUD window and they click outside it, it automatically disappears, but the Color Picker remains on-screen unless they specifically hit it's red close button.

Is there a way to programmatically dismiss or hide the color picker when we are done with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Swift language, you can do this to close the NSColorWell:

```
NSColorPanel.sharedColorPanel().orderOut(nil)
colorWellReach.deactivate()
```

Comment: Sorry, I should say that in this case "colorWellReach" is the name of the IBOutlet for the colorwell, as an example.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 2):

Call 
[[NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel] close];
where you want the Color Picker to disappear

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

`NSColorPanel.shared.close()`